# Android permissions issue with kotlin verion 1.3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I have an android app that using kotlin 1.3.
Now I am integrating permissions into it.
for that, I am adding the following dependencies.

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2"
```

But when I add these dependencies I am getting the following error in various files of the app like below.

```
'let((T) -> R): R' is only available since Kotlin 1.3.50 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.3
```

If I remove this dependency all errors will disappear but I can't handle runtime permissions.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to update your kotlin version

Comment: @tyczj Yes, I did that, but still getting the same error

Comment: post your apps `build.gradle` file where you declare the kotlin version

Answer (score -1):

Every Android app runs in a limited-access sandbox. If your app needs to use resources or information outside of its own sandbox, you can declare a permission and set up a permission request that provides this access. These steps are part of the workflow for using permissions.

If you declare any dangerous permissions, and if your app is installed on a device that runs Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, you must request the dangerous permissions at runtime by following the steps in this guide.

If you don't declare any dangerous permissions, or if your app is installed on a device that runs Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower, the permissions are automatically granted, and you don't need to complete any of the remaining steps on this page.